# Question about the proof of the existence of a splitting field

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, ideals, quotient-spaces, splitting-field

In the proof given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field, how are we talking about the roots of, for example, $p(x)$ in $F[x]$ quotient the ideal generated by $p(x)$? Isn't $p(x) = 0$ in this field? Then how do we discuss its roots? I thought if a polynomial were the zero polynomial in some field $G$ then it  doesn't make sense to speak about its roots in $G$.

Comment: I don’t have time for a full answer; probably someone else will explain fully. Let me just give an example, with $F=\Bbb Q$ and the polynomial $f=x^3-5$. By forming $Q[x]/(f)$ you get a cubic field, which to all intents and purposes is $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5\,)$. Now the polynomial $X^3-5$ has one root in this field, in fact $X^3-5=(X-\sqrt[3]5\,)(X^2+\sqrt[3]5X+\sqrt[3]{25}\,)$, and the quadratic factor has no roots in $K$. So you need to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about names of variables. Consider, for instance, the complex numbers, conventionally $\Bbb R[i]/(i^2+1)$, where we say that the real polynomial $x^2+1$ splits.

In short, the variable name you use to expand the field is now taken, so you can't use it as the generic variable name in a polynomial. So if you have a polynomial $p(x)$, which is irreducible over a field $F$ (which is to say, it is irreducible in the polynomial ring $F[x]$), then over the field $F[x]/(p(x))$, the polynomial $p(t)$ has at least one root (which is to say, it is reducible in the polynomial ring $(F[x]/(p(x)))[t]$).

(Note that $F[x]/(p(x))$ is not necessarily a splitting field for $p$. You are guaranteed the existence of one root, but nothing more. In some cases you do get all roots, but not in general.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I'm still confused about is why $p(x) = 0$ when we quotient out by $p(x)$ but $p(t) =/= 0$. Aren't they the same polynomial even though the indeterminate is different?

Comment: @Saad $x$ is an element of the quotient ring. So $p(x)$ is just an evaluation of the polynomial $p$ at that element. Think of the complex numbers case, for instance. Over the real numbers, in the polynomial ring with the variable $i$, the polynomial $p(i) = i^2+1$ has no roots. So we add a root of $p$ to $\Bbb R$ to get $\Bbb C = \Bbb R[i]/(i^2+1)$. Now, in this field we _do_ have $p(i) = 0$, as $i^2+1$ is just an element of the field, and we constructed the field specifically so that this element is $0$. Yet $p(x) = x^2+1$ is not the zero polynomial.

Comment: Oh, so $i^2 + 1 $ is an element of the field $C$ and the other is an element in $C[x]$? That would make sense. I would've liked an explanation like this on the wikipedia page, but I suppose that's what textbooks are for -:) Thank you.